# R: compare each value in the list is other value

Tags: r

I am new to R. I have a matrix **combine**, and I want to know whether each value of a certain column is greater than 0.05. How should I do that? And why the second line of code does not work? 9.65830710944783e-05 is less than 0.05, but the logical value is True for that

```
> head(combine[,"rollingUSGG5Y_significance"], 30)
 [1] NA                     NA                     NA                     NA                    
 [5] NA                     NA                     NA                     NA                    
 [9] NA                     "0.000340501400361469" NA                     NA                    
[13] NA                     NA                     "0.0180102687712968"   NA                    
[17] NA                     NA                     NA                     "0.00392196741941212" 
[21] NA                     NA                     NA                     NA                    
[25] "9.65830710944783e-05" NA                     NA                     NA                    
[29] NA                     "3.23767237214935e-07"
> head(combine[,"rollingUSGG5Y_significance"] > 0.05,30)
 [1]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA FALSE    NA    NA    NA    NA FALSE    NA    NA    NA
[19]    NA FALSE    NA    NA    NA    NA  TRUE    NA    NA    NA    NA  TRUE
```

Comment: first ensure they are numeric:  `head(as.numeric(combine[,"rollingUSGG5Y_significance"] )> 0.05,30)`

Comment: That works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A character column will evaluate `TRUE`/`FALSE` differently compared to a numeric column, when compared against a numeric value.  As @Onyambu noted in the comments, make sure you're evaluating numbers as numbers.

Here's a demonstration of how you'll get different boolean values in each case:

```r
set.seed(123)
n <- 10
a <- c(rnorm(n), NA_integer_)
b <- c(as.character(rnorm(n)), NA_character_)

df <- data.frame(a, b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df
             a                  b
1  -0.56047565   1.22408179743946
2  -0.23017749  0.359813827057364
3   1.55870831  0.400771450594052
4   0.07050839   0.11068271594512
5   0.12928774 -0.555841134754075
6   1.71506499   1.78691313680308
7   0.46091621  0.497850478229239
8  -1.26506123  -1.96661715662964
9  -0.68685285  0.701355901563686
10 -0.44566197 -0.472791407727934
11          NA               <NA>
```

You can see that `a` and `b` have different types:

```r
sapply(df, class)
          a           b 
  "numeric" "character"
```

And they'll evaluate differently against a numeric comparison:

```r
df[, "a"] > .05
# FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA

df[, "b"] > .05
# TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE    NA
```

Added explanation from @Onyambu in comments:

> Often the number is implicitly coerced to character. eg 3=="3" should return TRUE, and 3>"2.5" is TRUE, but 3e-1>"3" should return FALSE yet it returns TRUE because of the character read as 3e-1 and not as 0.3.

Comment: This is a good answer!! Also probably you should add that Often the number is implicitly coerced to character. eg `3=="3"` should return TRUE, and 3>"2.5" is TRUE, but 3e-1>"3" should return FALSE yet it returns TRUE because of the character read as 3e-1 and not as 0.3.